# Spilled powdered detergent on laptop

Tags: laptop

My friend spilled powdered detergent (Oxiclean) on her laptop. I took it apart as best I could, but without a service manual I am unsure how to completely disassemble it. Laptop is Asus K55A.

I think I got most of the detergent out of the case, but there might be a few granules left inside. Is that something I need to worry about? We haven't powered it on yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take some compressed air and blow it out, make sure it's not jamming up one of the fans and what not.  As long as there was never liquid inside, you should be alright!